# PHP check for correct answer

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created an html form with 20 questions, they are text and radio type, radio type questions has value of name, that is the answer, for example 
`How old are you?
* 200 (value="200")
* 300 (value="300")
* 400 (value="400")`

and then, when form is submited, it takes person, that submited form to a page, that inserts all data in database, but in 0 seconds with meta tag im getting user to last page, results, where he can see all answers, here is example http://prnt.sc/a8hvp0 (Jautajums = question) and answers go all down.

I want to know how could i insert in my code script or what to check answers, and if they are correct, while php create table he would make green background for those answers, what are correct

===================================================================

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link)
    {
        die ('Could not Connect: ' . mysql_error());    
    }
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected)
    {
        die('can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' .mysql_error())  ;
    }
echo "Hippy Nanny noo";

$value2 = $_POST['example'];
$value3 = $_POST['example12'];
$value4 = $_POST['example123'];
(Here are more of them)

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (example, example12, example123) Values ('$value2', '$value3', '$value4')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_close();
?>
```

==========================================================

## and the result page

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('','','','');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM form");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Example</th>
<th>Example12</th>
<th>Example123</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['example'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['example12'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['example123'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: we need  codes to help. So, please update your question with what you have done so far . ??

Comment: SELECT * from from will not work.
If user is not login then you need to pass Session ID as a unique key.
using that you can get record for that user only !